# How to call table valued function inside select Statement?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have created table valued function.
I am calling like this

```
select * from dbo.fun_sample(1)
```

It is working fine. I have table called Emp

```
Table Emp

Id Name Lname
1  Rani Kale
```

My select Statement is like this

```
Select id,Name,Lname from Emp
```

By passing value of id to function ,I want fetch table(having 2 column).But is not working

```
Select id,Name,Lname,(select * from dbo.fun_sample(1)) from Emp
```

Comment: what is result return from fun_sample(1).?

Comment: if its a table valued function then you have to use it as join. you can not use it directly in select statement

Comment: Table valued function returns a table and can be used just as a table in a sql query. So may be you can use a join with `Emp`

Comment: If the answer helped mark the question answered

Answer (score 8):

use CROSS APPLY

```
Select e.id,e.Name,e.Lname from Emp e
CROSS APPLY dbo.fun_sample(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your schema is like for the UDF, but something like this should point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT *
FROM Emp
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fun_sample(1)
```

Although it really makes more sense to substitute that `1` with some column from the table. Aside from that, I'm not really sure I understand what you're looking for, and I'll need more information.

Ultimately, approach you initially mentioned would be trying to store multiple columns (and rows, for that matter) in a single column. That's not possible in TSQL. A `CROSS APPLY` as used here could be likened to calling an `INNER JOIN`, except where the join is against data that is calculated for each row.

If your `1` was intentional, using an `INNER JOIN` will do.

```
SELECT *
FROM Emp
    INNER JOIN dbo.fun_sample(1) udf ON Emp.[column1] = udf.[column2]
```

Again, I can't give a working example there without the schema or your UDF.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select e.id,e.Name,e.Lname,f.id,f.Name,f.Lname from Emp e
CROSS APPLY dbo.fun_sample(1) as f
```